# Accessing Undefined Value in Javascript

Tags: javascript, file-upload, conditional-statements, undefined

I'm having some problems in tackling this.

A user can upload an image to a variable called photo_id in my form. I take the first file object in photo_id and send it to the database to create a file object.

```
    if (photo_id) {
     var file=photo_id[0]
    //send to database and set id to new object created
    }
```

However, sometimes, a user will click the file upload button but not add a file. A fileList object is still made and put into the photo_id variable but it has a length of 0, which makes it undefined.

[image]

In this scenario, when I run this:

```
 if (photo_id ) {
     var file=photo_id[0]
    ....
    }
```

I get

```
Cannot read property '0' of undefined
```

I need to check to make sure the FileList length is greater than 0 but even when I do this:

```
    if (photo_id[0].length >0) {
     var file=photo_id[0]
    //send to database and set id to new object created
    }
```

I get the error:

```
cannot read length of undefined
```

How can I check for both scenarios where the FileList exist and it's length is >0?

Comment: You're checking `photo_id` when you should be checking `photoImage`. You're not showing us where `photoImage` is defined, which is essential to this issue, but given your error message, it's not an empty list that you should check the length of, but undefined, and you should check for that.

Comment: @DavidHedlund photoImage was a typo, in any case, I'll need to change the names to make the variables sound more coherent. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are checking the length of the first element, but there is no first element. Use:

```
if (photo_id && photo_id.length > 0) {...}
```

Comment: `photo_id && ` is redundant and just more code the OP might not understand.